# How do I tell Mutt to not store sent messages?

Tags: mutt

I'm trying to figure out how to disable storing sent messages in Mutt.

Is there a `record` value in `.muttrc` that would make it happen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's the `copy` option to control if copies of messages you sent are saved. It's a quadoption, so can be set to `no` (which would accomplish what you want), `yes` to save messages automatically, as well as `ask-yes` or `ask-no` to have it ask on each message with you being able to choose the default.

Answer (score 23):

Just to make it a litte more clear:
in `/home/user/.muttrc`:

```
set copy=no
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do this with:

```
set record = "/dev/null"
```

From what I read there a lot of options for granular control. `record` being one of them. When `copy` is set to no all storage of mail copies is disabled. Whereas the `record` variable can be overridden `by the $force_name and $save_name variables, and the "fcc-hook" command.` [see the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/muttrc)

Technically I am misusing it in my example since it only specifies a save path. But it does give you more control by being able to override it with other variables.

However you **did** ask for a specific `record` value that would do the job ;-)